# email address completion in zsh

Tags: zsh, email, autocomplete

This is an extract from the `zsh` shell's manual:

> The completion system in zsh is programmable.  For  example, 
>    the  shell can be set to complete email addresses in arguments to
>          the mail command from your `~/.abook/addressbook`.

It's exactly what I want to do but I can't figure out the syntax.
This is the auto-generated line in my `.zshrc` :-

```
*zstyle ':completion:*' completer _expand _complete _ignored _correct _approximate*
```

I added `_email-addresses _email-mutt` to the end of it but it didn't work.
Nor can I figure out where `.abook/addressbook` comes into it.

Answer (score 0):

Found this. Changed the file to .mutt_aliases and it works for me.

https://www.zsh.org/mla/users/2002/msg00316.html